# Fixed header within table when scrolling the table

Tags: javascript, css, fixed-header-tables

## Problem:

I have a table that is too large to be a liquid style element for mobile. My solution was to make the `overflow-x: auto`. Works great and is pretty much how spread sheets on mobile apps work. One problem, the table can be confusing to read with the header being within the `offset-y` portion. I sometimes find myself scrolling back up just to see what column of data I'm looking at.

## Question:

Is there a way to keep the table header in a fixed position within the table itself using `CSS/JS - jQuery` so that when the user is scrolling through the data, the header is always showing just like you would expect it to be in a mobile app? (Numbers for mac also does this). I don't mind using CSS3 since this is for mobile.

### Other Things That Have The Same Behavior

- **Apple Numbers** When you scroll down and the headers should be out of view, they stay fixed until you pass up the table.
- **iPhone Instagram App** when scrolling through feed, the user's header stays in view until new post shows up.
- **iPhone Contacts App** When scrolling through *All Contacts* the letter section you're in stays on top until a new letter shows up.

I just want to make sure you guys know what I'm talking about because I couldn't find anything similar to what I wanted to do. Not sure If I'm typing in the wrong search terms or what. But it's pretty much a hybrid style between `float` and `fixed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code drops** has an excellent article on making the table headers fixed while scrolling.

The solution is based on JQuery and it works for both, row heading and column heading

**[Sticky Table Headers & Columns](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/01/09/sticky-table-headers-columns/)**

Comment: Sticky Table Headers! That's the term I'm looking for!

Comment: just see the article and the Demo on that page, you will be delighted!

Answer (score 2):

This is what you're looking for: https://css-tricks.com/persistent-headers/

It's been done many times before.

Comment: Persistent Headers. Ahhhhh! What glory it is to know the term for it!

Comment: Another term is "Sticky Headers" :)